# client/server win program

Tags: c#, client-server

i want to write a client/server win program.every client has a amount in it's fund that admin gives to them .now my question is how can every client send it's amount of fund to admin?and the amount of funds must be pend until admin accept them and then save changes for every client?
how can i do it??
thanks alot.

Comment: Er... what are you trying to do exactly? And exactly where are you having trouble at?

Comment: Um, that's a pretty big ask! Why don't you break the question down into more manageable chunks?

Comment: excusme, every client want to send it's amount to admin,how can i do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to make two programs communicate with each other?  You have many options.  I suggest you look into Windows Communication Foundation (WCF): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation sounds like the business rules can get complicated really fast. This is a psuedo code overview of how the system might look:

[image: Diagram]

This makes a few assumptions:

1. Your not utilizing a database from the clients directly.
2. Your client is storing the fund locally.
3. The client controls the pending state.
4. All logic is controlled from the method `Admin.Handle()`.

Your problem doesn't seem that well defined at this point. What happens if multiple clients access the same fund? How do clients know that another client has marked the fund as pending? Can you make the server store the funds and have the clients perform transaction requests against the server?